# How to use variable values from different classes WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I need some help with using variables that belong to one class inside another class.

I have `Semester` class that contains `Weeks` and `StartDate` properties.

In another class `CalcDisplay` I have method `CalculateStudyHours` that should calculate study hours based on `Weeks` and `StartDate` properties from `Semester` class.

I created a `Semester` object in my WPF class and I am passing through constructor `weeks` and `startDate` values that are provided by user.

```
 private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    int weeks = int.Parse(txtbWeeks.Text);
    DateTime startDate = (DateTime)dteDate.SelectedDate;

    Semester s = new Semester(weeks, startDate);

    ModuleListHandler.semesterDetails.Add(s);
    MessageBox.Show("Semester details added successfully");
    btnNext.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

`Semester` class

```
namespace TimeManagementClassLibrary
{
    public class Semester
    {
        public int Weeks { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        //default constructor
        public Semester()
        {

        }

        public Semester(int weeks, DateTime startdate)
        {
            Weeks = weeks;
            StartDate = startdate;
        }
    }
}
```

`CalcDisplay` class

```
public class CalcDisplay 
{
   //Method calculating study hours
   public double CalculateStudyHours()
   { 
      return (credits * 10 / weeks) - classHours;
   }          
}
```

What would be the most effective way to pass `credits` and `weeks` parameters to `CalcDisplay` class?

Comment: Pass values as arguments and calculate them: `CalculateStudyHours(int credits, int weeks, int classHours)`

Comment: Will those values passed represent the variables from Semester class which has the variable (weeks) and credits and classhours from the module class ?

Comment: Those values only indicate that to this method you can pass 3 parameters with int type and values will be assigned to those 3 variables.

Your method CalculateStudyHours won't do anything now unless you call it. So somewhere in your code you have to initialize new object `CalcDisplay calcDisplay = new CalcDisplay();` and then you can do `calcDisplay. CalculateStudyHours(someValue, someValue, someValue);` and it will be assigned to proper variables in your method.

Comment: Where credits  and  classHours are assigned? You code can't be compilled

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to my comment, let's imagine you have 3 classes:

```
public class Semester
{
    public int Weeks { get; set; }

    public Semester() { }
    public Semester(int weeks)
    {
        Weeks = weeks;
    }
}

public class Credit
{
    public int Credits { get; set; }

    public Credit() { }
    public Credit(int credits)
    {
        Credits = credits;
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public int ClassHours { get; set; }

    public SomeClass() { }
    public SomeClass(int classHours)
    {
        ClassHours = classHours;
    }
}
```

You obviously would create their instances and set/calculate it's `Weeks`, `Credits`, `ClassHours` values in some way.

Then you use that values to pass as arguments to some method of another class:

```
public class CalcDisplay 
{ 
    // May be static as uses passed in arguments values, non class members
    public static double CalculateStudyHours(int credits, int weeks, int classHours) 
    {          
       return (credits * 10 / weeks) - classHours;            
    }
}
```

And passing them from somewhere:

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get values in some way
    int weeks = int.Parse(txtbWeeks.Text);
    int credits = int.Parse(txtbCredits.Text);
    int classHours = int.Parse(txtbClassHours.Text);

    // Create your instances
    Semester s = new Semester(weeks);
    Credit c = new Credit(credits);
    SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(classHours);

    // Then pass it's properties values
    double result = CalcDisplay.CalculateStudyHours(c.Credits, s.Weeks, sc.ClassHours);
}
```

Or `CalcDisplay`class may has own fields/properties, which you set through its Constructor:

```
public class CalcDisplay 
{ 
    private int credits;
    private int weeks;
    private int classHours;

    // Constructor
    public CalcDisplay() {}
    public CalcDisplay(int credits, int weeks, int classHours) 
    {
        this.credits = credits;
        this.weeks = weeks;
        this.classHours = classHours;
    }

    // Non-static as we use class members
    public double CalculateStudyHours()
    {          
       return (credits * 10 / weeks) - classHours;            
    }
}

private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... same as upper

    CalcDisplay = new CalcDisplay(c.Credits, s.Weeks, sc.ClassHours);
    double result = c.CalculateStudyHours();
}
```